# Is there a simple way to effectively cat a filestream without writing to disk?

Tags: command-line, inputstream, virus-scanning

I'm working on a system to scan remote files for viruses. I'm downloading as a stream and would like to avoid saving unscanned files to disk for obvious reasons.

I can use [clamscan](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clamscan) for scanning the stream, but I'm not sure how to generate that stream in the command line. Both `echo` and the `command line` have the potential of playing games with what is actually being output if I did something like the following:

```
system("echo $data | clamscan -");
```

Are there any elegant solutions to achieving this that I am missing? Obviously I could probably filter the file dump with some stream editor before it hits clamscan, but that is definitely not elegant and prone to error, I would think.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`popen()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=popen&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html). However, it has its limitations. Anything more sophisticated will require you to play with your pipes and spawning of processes.